# Google maps directions API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, api

Mi problema es que estoy usando la API de google maps directions  y uso axios para hacer la solicitud, pero cuando ejecuto el codigo me dice que no le estoy pasando el parametro origin pero si se lo estoy pasando, ya lo intente con pasarle el parametro desde un principio en el objeto params pero nada, ya use la url con https y solo con http, estoy haciendo mis pruebas en un localhost. al final pondre el error que me sale.

```js
function directions(origen, destino){
  axios.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?',{
    params:{
      origin:origen,
      destination:destino,
      key:'mi clave ;)'
    }
  })
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log('Ha problemas willies');
  })
}

directions("ecatepec","CDMX")
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Failed to load http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=ecatepec&destination=CDMX&key=AIzaSyDmlJky0d55y9q9i7XY9oyIvxJoYfUv5_I: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed

Comment: y si pruebas agregando esto justo después de tu get? headers: {
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 },

Comment: justo antes de params

Comment: `function directions(origen, destino){
      axios.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?',{
        headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', },
        params:{
          origin:origen,
          destination:destino,
          key:'AIzaSyDmlJky0d55y9q9i7XY9oyIvxJoYfUv5_I'
        }
      })`
De esta forma @shadow paz?
si si es asi, igual me arroja error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no lo dice en la documentación (al menos la última vez que la leí), ese endpoint de google apis no está pensado para requests desde el front, por el problema de cross origin. Ellos simplemente no tienen habilitado el response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` y no hay mucho que hacer.

Tu request está bien, si cargas directamente 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=ecatepec&destination=CDMX&key=AIzaSyDmlJky0d55y9q9i7XY9oyIvxJoYfUv5_I  en tu browser, responde bien.

Pero si intentas hacer un request desde el front de tu aplicación, te dirá

```
Failed to load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=ecatepec&destination=CDMX&key=AIzaSyDmlJky0d55y9q9i7XY9oyIvxJoYfUv5_I: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Solución? Tienes que hacer el request desde el backend.